# Specificity of ROC curve plotting in reverse direction

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, roc

I wish to plot the ROC curve for a SVM classifier I have built but when I plot my data, the x axis (specificity) is plotting from 1.0 -> -1.0, see the image below.

[image: ROC Curve in Reverse]

In order to plot this I used the following:

```
> plot(roc(predictor = fit.down.Kernel$pred$Overshooting, response = fit.down.Kernel$pred$obs))
```

where fit.down.Kernel is my model, Overshooting is the target feature I wish to predict.

Obviously I have gone about this the wrong way, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Ultimately I have a bunch of models which I have trained using a variety of different datasets (upsampled, downsampled...) and I wish to visually compare their performance using the ROC curve. I guess I need to get the axis working properly before proceeding to  multiple plots.

Comment: The curve is between 1 and 0. What make you think you have obviously gone the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROCR` package in R. Refer to a code below and use with your Predictions vs actual results.

#### Prob.mod are predictions from various models ( 1, 2, 3) & y.test is your actual Overshooting

Use Prediction function from ROCR

```
prediction.mod1 <- prediction(prob.mod1, y.test) 
prediction.mod2 <- prediction(prob.mod2, y.test)
prediction.mod3 <- prediction(prob.mod3, y.test)
```

#### Calculating AUC

```
auc.mod1=performance(prediction.mod1, "auc")@y.values)
auc.mod2=performance(prediction.mod2, "auc")@y.values)
auc.mod3=performance(prediction.mod3, "auc")@y.values)
```

#### Plot AUCs

```
plot(auc.mod1, ylim=c(0.1, 1))
plot(auc.mod2, col=2, add=TRUE)
plot(auc.mod3, col=3, add=TRUE)
```